# <button> not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [Bootstrap markdown editor](https://github.com/inacho/bootstrap-markdown-editor). When we enable file upload feature, it generates following output, which results in a button. When user clicks on the button, file upload box is open.

```
<button title="Uplaod image" 
         class="btn btn-sm btn-default md-btn-file" 
         style="border: 1px solid red; border-image: none;" 
         type="button" data-mdtooltip="tooltip">

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
    <input class="md-input-upload" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" multiple="">
 </button>
```

Problem is this feature is not working in IE 11. Click on button does not open IE 11. This feature works fine in chrome.

If I remove the code which generates  to a div. after clicking on button, i get to see file upload dialog box.

```
<div title="Uplaod image" 
             class="btn btn-sm btn-default md-btn-file" 
             style="border: 1px solid red; border-image: none;" 
             data-mdtooltip="tooltip">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
        <input class="md-input-upload" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" multiple="">
     </div>
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it a known issue that button tag does not work well with IE 11 & is there any work around available?
2. Is it possible to use jquery/ javascript to find this button tag after its rendered and then replace it with `DIV` tag?

Comment: You've got an input inside a button? And that works in Chrome? Try encapsulating the form inside a form tag and putting the file input outside of the button...

There are no issues with IE11 and the button tag as such that I'm aware of.

Comment: The way I see it, IE is always slow in incorporating the spec - but at least they do so correctly. Chrome often allows additional behaviour (such as the one above) that should not work, or is at least not defined in the spec. It seems that Chrome allows event trickling down in this case, whereas IE does not. Probably because it's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 5):

It is forbidden, by the HTML specification, to place an `<input>` inside a `<button>`.

It also doesn't make sense to do so.

File inputs generate their own button for clicking on.

> Content model:
>   Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

(Input elements are interactive content)

[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jquery to explicitly invoke the click event of file upload:

```
document.querySelector(".md-btn-file").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        document.querySelector(".md-input-upload").click(clickEvent);
      });
```

This causes chrome to open the file upload dialog box two times.  I will add another check to see if broswer is IE then only add this event.